# Multiple test cases in one Selenium web driver instance

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to programming so please be patient, but to the point.

I am creating few test cases using Selenium Web Driver, I have to check functionality of webpage to which I have to login using password and later with SMS code that I receive on my phone. I want to do this ONE TIME ONLY, so I want to use ONE instance of Web Driver for all my test cases (I know it is not recommended, but it will save a lot of time and sending 30 SMS, code from SMS is entered manually via Terminal).

My code looks something like this:

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Safari()

    def test_LoginIn(self):
        browser = self.browser
        (Here I am looking for buttons and clicking on them)

    def test_MyDevices(self):
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('Some XPATH').click()
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And here is my problem after performing `test_LoginIn` I want to start another test `test_MyDevices` because MyDevice tab is right after logging in on the same page as first test is ended, but I can't because next test want to create new Web Driver Instance instead of doing test in the same instance.

In current version I receive this error:
[Error after running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfUjB.png)

I read a lot about this issue but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.
I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same instance of the webdriver for all of your tests. You will just need to instantiate the webdriver once, and then use it throughout your tests.